# Time lag while connecting from Talend-SalesForce using tSalesForceConnection component

Tags: salesforce, talend

I am trying to connect to SalesForce using SalesForce connector in Talend. Now when I send the connection request, I can see that the connection is established after ~2 seconds and as soon as the connection is established to SalesForce url, the response is in milliseconds. I am using `tSalesForceConnection`  to establish the connection to SalesForce from Talend but there is a time lag in that process.

I am using `oAuth` authentication type to authenticate with SalesForce server

An example using `tsttatcacter` logs we see between begin and end it is taking 2 seconds.

```
2020-10-22 13:52:38|CgqWpf|CgqWpf|CgqWpf|16220|sample|samplelog|_PF7PIBPKEeuGlI4APhARAg|0.1|Default||begin||

2020-10-22 13:52:38|CgqWpf|CgqWpf|CgqWpf|16220|sample|samplelog|_PF7PIBPKEeuGlI4APhARAg|0.1|Default|tSalesforceConnection_2|begin||

2020-10-22 13:52:39|CgqWpf|CgqWpf|CgqWpf|16220|sample|samplelog|_PF7PIBPKEeuGlI4APhARAg|0.1|Default|tSalesforceConnection_2|end|success|1478

1515 milliseconds

2020-10-22 13:52:39|CgqWpf|CgqWpf|CgqWpf|16220|sample|samplelog|_PF7PIBPKEeuGlI4APhARAg|0.1|Default||end|success|1515
```

Does anyone have any idea why is there a time lag in establishing connection via Talend and if there are ways to improve it?